# Access request in __init__ in ModelForm

Tags: django, django-forms

How can I access request in `__init__` form?

**forms.py**

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)


    def clean(self):
        ... access the request object via self.request ...
```

**views.py**

```
myform = MyForm(request.POST, request=request)
```

but what if I use class based views `FormView`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to access request in your `MyForm` you can override the `FormView.get_form_kwargs` method.

```
def get_form_kwargs(self):
    kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
    kwargs.update({'request': self.request})
    return kwargs
```

[FormView source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/edit.py)

> ```
> class FormMixin(ContextMixin):
>     ...
>     def get_form(self, form_class=None):
>         """
>         Returns an instance of the form to be used in this view.
>         """
>         if form_class is None:
>             form_class = self.get_form_class()
>         return form_class(**self.get_form_kwargs())
>
>     def get_form_kwargs(self):
>         """
>         Returns the keyword arguments for instantiating the form.
>         """
>         kwargs = {
>             'initial': self.get_initial(),
>             'prefix': self.get_prefix(),
>         }
>
>         if self.request.method in ('POST', 'PUT'):
>             kwargs.update({
>                 'data': self.request.POST,
>                 'files': self.request.FILES,
>             })
>         return kwargs
>         if form_class is None:
>             form_class = self.get_form_class()
>         return form_class(**self.get_form_kwargs())
> ```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the user_passes_test decorator, documented at:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.user_passes_test

```
def my_test(user):
    return user.username == 'me'

@user_passes_test(my_test)
class MyView(FormView):
    ...
```